# my python printlinkedlist function prints the memory instead of the linked list

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

i recently started learning data structures and algorithms and i decided that i ll get started with linked lists. and after i watched a lot of tutorials about it, i decided to create it on my own, but i have some problems. my print function prints a memory adress instead of the linked lists. i realized that i am trying to print an object but the problem is that i didnt find the flaw. please help

```
class Node:
        
            def __init__(self,data,next=None):
                self.data = data
                self.next = next
        
        class LinkedList:
        
            def __init__(self,head=None):
                self.head = head
        
            def append(self,data):
                if self.head is None:
                    self.head = Node(data)
                    return
                else:
                    itr = self.head
                    while itr.next:
                        itr = itr.next
                    else:
                        itr = Node(data)
                        itr.next = Node(data)
         def print(self):
                itr = self.head
                while itr:
                    print(itr.data," --> ",end="")
                    itr = itr.next
                    return
                else:
                    print("None")
                    return
        
            def reverse(self):
                pass
        
        linked = LinkedList()
        linked.print()
        linked.append(Node(3))
        linked.print()
        linked.append(Node(7))
        linked.print()
        linked.append(Node(10))
        linked.print()
```

Comment: `linked.append(Node(3))`  -->  `linked.append(3)`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp wow, it works now, thanks. but it only print threes. i probably have another problem

Answer (score 0):

You pass a `Node` to `append` and then that creates a 2nd `Node`. Just pass the number.

Also, you don't seem to use the `while/else` construct properly. The `else` block is entered if the `while` part ran to completion (the `while` condition is no longer true) - i.e. there was no `break` or exception.

Also, in `print()` you have something like:

```
while some_condition:
    # Other stuff...
    return
```

This means the loop only executes once (unless there is a `continue`). So no matter how large the list is, only the first item gets printed.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data,next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self,head=None):
        self.head = head

    def append(self,data):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(data)
        else:
            itr = self.head
            while itr.next:
                itr = itr.next
            itr.next = Node(data)

    def print(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("None")
            return
        itr = self.head
        while itr:
            print(itr.data," --> ",end="")
            itr = itr.next
        print()

linked = LinkedList()
linked.print()
linked.append(3)
linked.print()
linked.append(7)
linked.print()
linked.append(10)
linked.print()
```

Comment: wow thank you very much sir